# DataSet in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a c# class which looks like:

```
class Response
{
  public string ResponseStatus {get; set;}
  public DataSet Data {get; set;}
}
```

This is just an example I have few more properties in my class.

My question is that how can I Get this object from WebApi in my javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "localhost:50231/api/dataaccessserver/GetData",
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: dasRequest, 
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    }, 
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr)); 
    }
});
```

I have enable cross-origin resource sharing and now I am able to get JSON string.

Now I am trying to post JSON string to Web Api and it is deserializing the json string to my object (Response) but it is not deserializing the dataset. following is the json string which I am passing to the api.

{"Status":1,"Data":{"MyTbl":[{"ID":1,"Name":"x"},{"ID":2,"Name":"y"}]}}

Following is my code which I am using to POST data to Web Api:

```
   function postdata() {
       var da = $('#res').html();
       $.ajax({
           url: '/api/test/Post',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.parse(da),
           success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
           },
           error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                     alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));  
           }            
        });
}
```

Following is the action in Web Api:

```
   public string Post(Response Data)
    { 

        return  "success";
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, show your code, point out exactly where you're stuck and reason about it. If no, why not?

Comment: $.ajax({
             url:     "http://localhost:50231/api/dataaccessserver/GetData",
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: dasRequest,
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                
             },
             error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(JSON.stringify(xhr)); }
         });

Comment: this is my code in js file. but I am always getting error.

Comment: BTW, you can always edit your question. Posting code in the comments is not useful.

Comment: "I am getting an error" is not an error description. Please put some more effort into your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask